# Different behaviour by double tap on touchpad and with buttons

Tags: touchpad, sublime-text

I am having a very strange problem and I have no idea how to reproduce it for someone else to debug. In sublime text 3, I have to triple tap on touchpad to select a word, while double tap using the buttons of the touchpad. That is, one more click if directly tapping on touchpad. Same is applicable for selecting a line. This happens only in sublime text.
I am using Kubuntu 18.04. I have tried deleting the sublime-text config folder and reinstalling sublime text 3. Does anybody have any idea how could this happen, as to what I know, a tap on touchpad is same as clicking left click once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sublime text version in which I encountered the error was `3.1`. It was resolved in version `3.2`. The changelog has this:

> Linux: Improved input method (IM) support -fcitx, ibus, etc

Though I can't understand the problem, it seems to me like a bug from the devs.